# R How to set tick mark size using a trellis theme in Lattice?

Tags: r, themes, lattice, trellis

I'm trying to use a trellis theme to set all my graphing parameters to keep my plotting statements short. I can't seem to find the correct trellis parameter access tick mark length (or any scale parameters for that matter).

```
library(lattice)

x = runif(100)
my.theme = trellis.par.get()
my.theme$axis.line = list(tck=c(4))     # this does not work
dp <- densityplot(~x)

# this works, but I want to do it using a theme
# dp <-densityplot(~x, scales=list(y=list(tck=c(4)))) 

png("dp.png", width=400, height=200)
trellis.par.set(my.theme)
plot(dp); dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick lengths for each of the plot's axes are controlled by (elements of) `axis.components` in **lattice**'s graphical parameter list.

Run `str(trellis.par.get("axis.components"))` to see what you are aiming for, and then do something like the following:

```
mytheme <- list(axis.components = list(left = list(tck=4), right = list(tck=4)))
trellis.par.set(mytheme)
densityplot(~x)
```

[image]